# Relative reference to rows in large data set

Tags: r, data.table, na

I have a very large data set (millions of rows) where I need to turn into `NA` certain rows when a `var1` equals "Z". However, I also need to turn into `NA` the preceding row to a row with `var1="Z"`. 
E.g.:

```
id  var1
1   A
1   B
1   Z
1   S
1   A
1   B
2   A
2   B
3   A
3   B
3   A
3   B
4   A
4   B
4   A
4   B
```

In this case, the second row and the third row for `id==1` should be `NA`. 
I have tried a loop but it doesn't work as the data set is very large.

```
for (i in 1:length(df$var1)){
        if(df$var1[i] =="Z"){
                df[i,] <- NA
                df[(i-1),] <-- NA
        }
}
```

I have also tried to use data.table package unsuccessfully. Do you have any idea of how I could do it or what is the right term to look for info on what I am trying to do?

Comment: It should be by `id` or the preceding row can be from the previous `id` too?

Comment: indeed that could be the case. Will delete/update my answer if it's per id.

Comment: The preceding row is always the same id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe do it like this using data.table:

```
df <- as.data.table(read.table(header=T, file='clipboard'))
df$var1 <- as.character(df$var1)

#find where var1 == Z
index <- df[, which(var1 == 'Z')]
#add the previous lines too
index <- c(index, index-1)
#convert to NA
df[index, var1 := NA  ]
```

Or in one call:

```
df[c(which(var1 == 'Z'), which(var1 == 'Z') - 1), var1 := NA  ]
```

Output:

```
> df
    id var1
 1:  1    A
 2:  1   NA
 3:  1   NA
 4:  1    S
 5:  1    A
 6:  1    B
 7:  2    A
 8:  2    B
 9:  3    A
10:  3    B
11:  3    A
12:  3    B
13:  4    A
14:  4    B
15:  4    A
16:  4    B
```

Comment: After hours thinking about this, I just tested your code in my original data set and it works blazing fast! Thanks so much @LyzandeR!

Comment: You are very welcome @user3507584 :). This is the awesome power of data.table. Glad I could help.

Comment: I have millions of rows and sometimes you find funny things. Is it possible to read the answer proposed by @DavidArenburg again?

Comment: I m sure he ll undelete it in a while since you pinged him.

Comment: I've undeleted, though I just saw this by mistake

Answer (score 2):

If you want to take in count the preceding indices only if they are from the same `id`, I would suggest to use the `.I` and `by` combination which will make sure that you are not taking indecies from previous `id`

```
setDT(df)[, var1 := as.character(var1)]
indx <- df[, {indx <- which(var1 == "Z") ; .I[c(indx - 1L, indx)]}, by = id]$V1
df[indx, var1 := NA_character_]
df

#     id var1
#  1:  1    A
#  2:  1   NA
#  3:  1   NA
#  4:  1    S
#  5:  1    A
#  6:  1    B
#  7:  2    A
#  8:  2    B
#  9:  3    A
# 10:  3    B
# 11:  3    A
# 12:  3    B
# 13:  4    A
# 14:  4    B
# 15:  4    A
# 16:  4    B
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a base `R` approach:

```
x = var1=='Z'
df[x | c(x[-1],F), 'var1'] <- NA

#   id var1
#1   1    A
#2   1 <NA>
#3   1 <NA>
#4   1    S
#5   1    A
#6   1    B
#7   2    A
#8   2    B
#9   3    A
#10  3    B
#11  3    A
#12  3    B
#13  4    A
#14  4    B
#15  4    A
#16  4    B
```